# Unable to populate json to FormArray. TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: json, angular, api

I am receiving this json format from api and need to populate it into FormArray. But am getting TypeError: data.map is not a function. Below is the code snippet.

```
{
    "data": [ 
        {
            "id": "ASR4324368",
            "name": "TTTTT",
            "amount": 100
        },
        {
            "id": "GTH435435435",
            "name": "AAAAA",
            "amount": 500
        }
    ]   
}


getProductJson() {
    this.httpClient.request('GET', 'getProductJSON', { withCredentials: true })
        .subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => {
                this.productForm = this.fb.group({
                    product: this.fb.array(
                        data.map(datum => this.generateDatumFormGroup(datum))
                    )
                });
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
    );
}

private generateDatumFormGroup(datum) {
    return this.fb.group({
        id: this.fb.control({ value: datum.id, disabled: false }),
        productName: this.fb.control({ value: datum.name, disabled: false }),
        productAmt: this.fb.control({ value: datum.amount, disabled: false }),
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe your subscription returns object with property name 'data' of type 'array'. in that case, try `(res:any)=> { let MyArray:any[] = res.data; }`

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you get data? to check use pipe(tap)

```
 this.httpClient.request('GET', 'getProductJSON', { withCredentials: true })
    .pipe(tap(res=>{console.log(res)})) //<--add this line
    .subscribe(....rest-of your code...)
```

NOTE: I feel strange your request (but really I don't know if is ok) I ususally use some like

```
this.httpClient.get('http://myapi/api/controller/action', { withCredentials: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified to the below and was working.

```
getProductJson() {
    this.httpClient.request('GET', 'getProductJSON', { withCredentials: true })
        .subscribe(
            (data: any[]) => {
                this.raw = data;
                this.productObj = this.raw.data;

                this.productForm = this.fb.group({
                    product: this.fb.array(
                        this.productObj.map(datum => this.generateDatumFormGroup(datum))
                    )
                });
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
    );
}
```